# Tensorflow custom activation function with tf.cond

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to write a custom activation function using `tf.custom_gradient`. Specifically I want to use the `taylor` expansion of 1/x for x<1 and 1/x otherwise. Here's my code:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def taylor_inverse(x):
    def func(x):
        return(tf.cond(x<1, taylor(x), tf.math.reciprocal(x)))

    def grad(upstream):
        return(tf.cond(upstream<1, taylor_grad(upstream), inv_diff(upstream)))
    return func(x), grad

@tf.function
def taylor(x):
    return(4 - 6 * x + 4 * x ** 2 - x ** 3)
    
@tf.function
def taylor_grad(x):
    return(-3 * x ** 2 + 8 * x - 6)

@tf.function
def inv_diff(x):
    return(-tf.math.reciprocal(x)**2)
```

I get the error message:

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

Equations are *-x<sup>3</sup>+4x<sup>2</sup>-6x+4* and for the gradient *-3x<sup>2</sup>+8x-6*, and I get error in this line:

```
layer_inverse = Lambda(lambda x: taylor_inverse(x),output_shape=(1,))(layer)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: It would be faster to help if you add the code where it fails not just the functions. Also add the math equations you need to be implemented.

Comment: layer_inverse = Lambda(lambda x: taylor_inverse(x),output_shape=(1,))(layer)

Comment: And the equations are -x^3 +4x^2-6x+4 and for the gradient -3x^2 + 8x -6

Comment: Where does the `Lambda` come from? Please share a piece of code we can run without guessing where each thing comes from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.cond` second and third arguments should be callable function. So, use it like this:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def taylor_inverse(x):
    def func(x):
        return(tf.cond(x<1, lambda: taylor(x), lambda: tf.math.reciprocal(x)))

    def grad(upstream):
        return(tf.cond(upstream<1, lambda: taylor_grad(upstream), lambda: inv_diff(upstream)))
    return func(x), grad
```